# Routing Error in Topics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am writing an application , which User can create Topics and others can make posts on that topic.

I am stuck with this error :

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"topics", :id=>nil}
```

my route.rb :

```
MyPedia2::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :users

    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :topics, only: [:show, :create, :destroy] 

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

    root to: 'static_pages#home'

    match '/topics/:id', to: 'topics#show'
```

my rake route shows :

```
   topics POST   /topics(.:format)         topics#create
      topic GET    /topics/:id(.:format)     topics#show
            DELETE /topics/:id(.:format)     topics#destroy
    root        /                         static_pages#home
               /topics/:id(.:format)     topics#show
```

and my topics controller is:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class TopicsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, only: :destroy


  def show
        @topic = Topic.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

    def create
        @topic = current_user.topics.build(params[:topic])
        if @topic.save
            flash[:success] = "Konu oluşturuldu!"
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render 'static_pages/home'
        end
    end

  def destroy
    @topic.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end
  private

    def correct_user
      @topic = current_user.topics.find_by_id(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path if @topic.nil?
    end
end
```

Is there a fix for this ?
EDIT : I found that _topics.html.erb fails
I found what breakes the code :

```
<% for topic in @topics do %>  
  <li><%=link_to topic.title, topic_path(@topic) %></li>  

 <%= will_paginate @topics %>
<% end %>
```

topic_path(@topic] part is wrong. How can i make it to use id?

Comment: That seems to be because you're doing a GET on 'topics' with no ID. You need to provide an ID in the URL.

Comment: I found what breakes the code :

Comment: If I use localhost:3000 .. I get this error .. http://localhost:3000/topics/1 works... I have to find a way to use ID as primary key in topics.

Comment: You have two issues here. One is you can't 'show' a topic without specifying a topic. The second is because your root route is being directed to show a topic, with no topic specified. I'm pretty sure you should have an index action and view, and direct the root route to that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because your collection is '@topics', and each element is 'topic', not '@topic'. But you're close. Try this:

```
<li><%=link_to topic.title, topic_path(topic) %></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of thinking , now i can see my mistake. I used show method in my topics controller but i did not have show.html.erb in my views/topics.

If you want to show your topics you must use these methods:

1) in config/routes.rb use :

```
match '/topics/:id', to: 'topics#show'
```

2) in the model i used
belongs_to :user,:foreign_key => "user_id"

3) link as :

```
<li><%=link_to topic.title, **topic_path(topic)** %></li>
```

4) and prepare the template you mentioned in the route.

I hope this help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li><%=link_to topic.title, topic_path(:id => @topic.id) %></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your routes should probably read:

```
resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :topics, :only => [:show, :create, :destroy]
```